# Why didn’t the Charles Manson character appear in Spahn Ranch?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, analysis, once-upon-a-time-in-hollywood

In the real life version of the Charles Manson murders, Manson gave orders to his cult gang to execute everyone under the house where a music producer used to live. But the movie version in Once upon a time in ... Hollywood, we just see the Manson character once in the entire movie when he visits the estate of Polanski’s, but quickly shunned away by their friend Jay Sebring.

I expected this Manson character to appear once at least in the Spahn Ranch where the family members/associates (Tex and the 3 female characters) of Manson are shown to be living. So my question is did Manson really order this execution in background which was not shown in the movie’s context? Or the hippies just turned up looking for a random kill?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, are you asking whether he ordered the execution in the film (just off screen) or did he really order the execution in reality?

Comment: I'm with @moonCat93 It's unclear if you want to know why the character wasn't included much vs wanting to know the real world truth about Manson giving the order vs in wanting to know the "in universe" truth about it?

Comment: @moonCat93 : Yes my question is in regards to the film.

Comment: @DarthLocke :  More about his presence in the film. I didn’t quite infer from the storyline how and where he ordered the execution

Comment: @Inian, if you edit your answer to make that more clear, it would be VERY helpful. :)

Comment: It's not a biopic. Many details were changed by QT.